# How to avoid restarting activity automatically , when i testing with plug & unplug usb in power saver mode only

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-usb

When mobile battery server mode on , testing my app i plug & unplug usb.. app activity restarting.. only with battery server mode on..

Comment: I guess you mean battery saving mode. I also guess when the "charger" is disconnected you get a "configuration change" like e.g. when the display orientation changes. You can read about [handling configuration changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes) in Android documentation or search Stack Overflow with that term.

Comment: thanks markus kauppinen, 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element
i used     android:configChanges=  "uiMode" , and it worked

Answer (score 1):

```html
Thank you all , i put to - uiMode to cofigChanges it worked

<activity   android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden|mcc|mnc|uiMode"
            android:name=".menu5"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />
```